# Using Team Explorer and VisualSVN simultaneously in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, svn, version-control, tfs

Maybe a bit of a newbie question, but I don't want to mess up my visual studio installation at the moment :p

I currently have [Visual Studio 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/default.aspx) installed with Team Explorer and TFS Power Tools which I use for work and a few projects on Codeplex. Today I discovered an interesting tool called [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/) which I would like to try out since I don't really have a TFS server for personal hobby projects. But will installing a second source control client thingy create a mess? Or how would that work? Does anyone have an experience with working with both of these installed at the same time for different projects?

By simultaneously I don't mean using both for the same projects or solutions of course, but being able to use the same visual studio installation for both projects on TFS and on SVN servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have VSS and VisualSVN on the same computer so I can tell you it is possible to have both. I wouldn't recommend using both tools in the same project, but for different projects it should be no problem

I still have VSS for legacy applications; every now and then I move one of them to SVN, and then I simply unbind it from VSS. The new versions of the project are stored on SVN, but I still have access to old versions using the VSS explorer.

Comment: Nice. Sounds good. Think I will try it out some time soon then :)

Answer (score 1):

In VS under Tools -> Options -> Source Control it lets you select which source control plugin you want to use. It lets me switch between VSS, MSSCCI, and TFS. I would assume it works the same way for Visual SVN.

If you load a project it seems to automatically switch to the plugin for that project. I haven't done much of this just a little bit as I was migrating from VSS to TFS. It seemed like it wouldn't be too hairy to do.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the automatic switching. Going into Tools and Options everytime would be aweful... How does it work when creating a new project? Do you get to choose then? Or do you have to close all open solutions, make the switch and then create the new project?

Comment: VisualSVN does not use the standard source control integration API. It's a regular add-in that interacts directly with TortoiseSVN.

Comment: I think it switches between them based on the source control bindings on the project. So if it's a new project whatever you bind it to will be what it switches to next time you open. 

Thanks jeroenh that's good to know.

Answer (score 0):

This *should* be entirely possible.

Answer (score 0):

I've got TFS, Tortoise CVS, and Tortoise SVN all installed on my system.  No conflicts -- at least as long as you don't attempt to use more than one for the same project.  I should say that I don't use them through VS, though.  I would expect that it would work as long as the client includes integration with VS since you can change SCC clients.  Typically I use CVS/SVN on older projects that I haven't migrated to TFS and use them through Windows explorer.

Comment: Yeah, using them outside of visual studio I don't really think would be a problem. Then it would mostly just be two separate programs. Unless they were integrated in windows explorer and overlapped somehow...

Answer (score 0):

Ryan mentioned "If you load a project it seems to automatically switch to the plugin for that project." - is this everyone's experience?  I'm using VS 08 Team System with the Ankhsvn VS08 plugin and the build in Microsoft Visual SourceSafe source control plug-in.  I have different projects with bindings to svn and others with VSS bindings.  Visual Studio does not detect the source control bindings automatically when I open a project or solution.  So, if I have the VS Tools...Options..Source Control setting configured to Ankh but open a project with VSS bindings I don't see any source control UI functionality in the Solution Explorer.  It appears to have no bindings.  My only option is to manual change back to the Microsoft Visual SourceSafe source control plug-in.

Does anyone know how to get the VS Team System to automagically detect the project bindings and choose the appropriate source control plugin, as mentioned by Ryan?